# Accessing the Blob or the file share from Azure HTTP function

Tags: azure

I am pretty new to Azure. The task is very simple but I have no idea how to do it.
I simply want to access a file that is stored into a blob container or I can also move it to file share but either way I don't find any useful resource to achieve the same. Please note that I don't want a blob trigger function, it is just that my azure HTTP function needs to read the file from Azure storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Azure function you could access the blobs (files) using the appropriate Azure Blob Storage client library based on the language you chose to implement your function. See c# examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples)